# Clear all values within a nested struct passed to a function by address

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Here are my structures:

```
struct Name {
    char firstName[31];
    char middleInitial[7];
    char lastName[36];
};

struct Contact
{
    struct Name name;
};
```

I have an array of Contact structures which is passed by address to this function:

```
void updateContact(struct Contact contacts[], int size)
{
        // More code up here that deals with finding the index 
        // and such

        contacts[index].name = { 0 }; // Expected an expression before {
}
```

The name struct is populated with data and I would simply like to reinitialize all values contained so I can create new data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can zero out one contact like this:

```
        memset(contacts[index].name, 0, sizeof contacts[index].name);
```

This will result in all strings being zero-length.

---

Alternatively you can assign NUL just to the first character of each string like this, but this requires that you know and track all members of `struct Name`:

```
        contacts[index].name.firstName[0] = '\0';
        contacts[index].name.middleInitial[0] = '\0';
        contacts[index].name.lastName[0] = '\0';
```

---

Alternatively your compiler may support this syntax:

```
        contacts[index].name = (struct Name){ 0 };
```

Comment: keeping track of members arn't a problem, i saw this as a solution already but im suprised their isn't a easier way of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
contacts[index].name = { 0 };
```

this only works during initialization and this statement is an assignment.

Suggest:

```
memset( contacts[ index ].name, 0, sizeof( contacts[ index ].name ) );
```

However, to clear ALL the fields in the struct suggest:

```
memset( contacts[ index ], 0, sizeof( contacts[ index] ) );
```

However, to clear the whole array suggest:

```
memset( contacts, 0, sizeof( contacts ) );
```

Comment: Please do not fiddle with answers when the fiddling adds no value.   In general, capitalization means nothing.  removing the spacing that was added for readability should not be removed

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest you do it using malloc so you can easily free the memory using free(pointer);

Change your struct to this:

```
struct Name {
    char* firstName;
    char* middleInitial;
    char* lastName;
};
```

This is for when you make the struct:

```
Name name;
name.firstName = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 31);
```

//REPEAT FOR THE OTHER STRINGS

```
free(name.firstName);
free(name.middleInitial);
free(name.lastName);
```